# Python Pinging -t

Tags: python

I have a batch program that simply pings in loop with 'ping adress -t'. Adress being whatever I'm trying to ping at the time.

I'd like to do something similiar with python, but without the popup of a command prompt window and thus I'd like to avoid anything that would do this. I want a way to print it ONLY to the python window, so I can use it in my Tkinter program.

This is what I would originially thought would work, and it does, but I want the output to be in the python window, not in the command prompt.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["ping", "google.com", "-t"])
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["ping", "-t"])
```

Comment: This prints it to the command prompt, I want it to print to the python window, thanks for the help, though!